# How do I get the query result from ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync?

Tags: entity-framework-core-3.0

Entity Framework Core 3.0 introduced a new method `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` as documented here :

[RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlinterpolatedasync?view=efcore-3.0)

The sample query is this:

`context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SearchBlogs]({userSuppliedSearchTerm})");`

How do I get the results returned by this query? Is it even possible?

Comment: For queries use one of the `FromSql` methods - see [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Answer (score 3):

`ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` returns the number of rows affected as the task result. Use `FromSqlInterpolated` to get results - see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16991#issuecomment-518796682) for usage example

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating  records in the database you will use ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync and it returns an interger indicating total number of records affected by the change and if you also have stored procedure in the database that is meant for update or delete or create records, you could use ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync such as;

```
var affectedrows = await context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"Exec CustomerUpdate {id}");
```

where id is the expected stored procedure parameter in this context.
But for your question,
You need to do the following;

1. Create class say HeadCash ,

   ```
   [Keyless]
   public class HeadCash
   {
         public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Add the class to DBContext as DbSet such as;

   ```
     public virtual DbSet<HeadCash> HeadCash { get; set; }
   ```
3. Create method to generate the data you need such as in your executing class;

   ```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<HeadCash>> CheckHeadCash(string Id)
    {
        try
        {
            var headcash =await _context.HeadCash.FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC 
              GetHeadCash {Id}").ToListAsync();

            return headcash;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
   ```

Note, remember to add [KeyLess] attribute on the class as in step 1 above.